# What are they called?

Tags: knowledge, visual

**Something** is missing from the image below. Can you figure out what that is? Complete the image to the right and then give me the answer which consists of two words.

---

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are called:

> **CLASSICAL ELEMENTS**

The grids of boxes on the left tell us what should be added in the corresponding boxes on the right (yes, *grids* - plural...). Because the 10x10 arrangement of boxes is actually...

> ...four 5x5 arrangements of boxes positioned next to each other. And each 5x5 sub-grid should be interpreted as if they contained **letters of the English alphabet**, like a [Polybius square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_square) (a tool used to help encode/decode certain types of cipher). If we do this, the top-left sub-grid would look like this, with the diagonal line in row 2 indicating that I and J share a space (a common device so that all 26 letters fit):
>
>  [image: Polybius square]
>
>  If we focus on the spaces shaded grey, these indicate the letters AEGILNRT - an anagram of **TRIANGLE**.

In fact...

> ...if you look at all four sub-grids, you will see that the top-right one is identical to top-left, and the bottom two are merely reflections of those above them. This suggests we need to add *triangles to each of the 4 boxes on the right - the bottom two being reflections of the top two*.

If we do this, accommodating the lines already in position, we get the following (labelled) diagram:

> [image: The right-hand boxes augmented with triangles to form classical element symbols]
>
>  What are these? These are commonly-used symbols for the **[classical elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element)** - our two-word answer!

Comment: Well explained and great job!